# ggplot set start in top in geom_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble with setting the start point on the top for `geom_polar(theta = "y")` when having positive and negative values with different minimum and maximum. It works when setting equal y-limits (see p4). How do I set the starting point correctly?

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:10], y = seq(-1.7, 1.2, length.out = 10))

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + guides(fill = F)
p1 <- plot + coord_polar(theta = "y")
p2 <- plot + coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)
p3 <- plot + coord_polar(theta = "y", start = pi) #does not work
p4 <- plot + coord_polar(theta = "y", start = pi) + ylim(c(-2,2)) # does work
```

[image: Plot]
<sub>(source: [ahschulz.de](http://www.ahschulz.de/pub/overflow/geom_polar.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the `0` on top, but don't want to specify limits. You can rescale by `max(y)/diff(range(y))` like that

```
plot + coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 2*pi*max(df$y)/diff(range(df$y)))
```